# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I have web services which I have hosted under the virtual directory named "TestServices". The client program has the web references added to it and those references point to the "TestServices" virtual directory in my development environment.

Our test environment is replica of the production and there virtual directory name is "ConfiguratorApplication". When I run the client exe on the test environment i get the exception mentioned in title. The correct url is mentioned in the application config file.

How to deal with such a scenario when virtual directory names may not match but you still add web references during developement or create proxy classed of the web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.url.aspx) property of your proxy object to any location that implements the same service description as the original web reference:

```
yourClientProxy.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["yourUrlKeyInAppConfig"];
```

Comment: I am setting the URL to the correct virtual directory as you mentioned. I can browse the service in IE. But still I am facing the problem.

Comment: @CSharpLearner, can you give more details about the exception you receive (e.g. its backtrace)?

Comment: Setting the proxy URL as you stated, solved my problem. Thank you. But I would like to know further: What if I need to host the web services on multiple servers in my environment? How to manage this thing?